# Finished basement outlets, GFCI or AFCI?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, building-regulations

I am finishing a basement and I am not sure if I need to install GFCI or AFCI outlets. Is it better to use a GFCI/AFCI breaker instead of the outlets?

NOTE: the finished basement will be used as a home theater/media room. There will be a dry bar also.

Comment: @isherwood made the changes you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's officially considered "habitable space", then it's a finished basement and GFCI is not required.

AFCI protection *is* required.  An AFCI breaker, is probably the cheapest and easiest way to provide the protection.